# NodeJs - RabbitMq - Handle Null Message in Queue

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, message-queue

I have a`RabbitMq Helper` class that implements the following function to receive and process messages:

```
async GetMessageFromQueue() {
    try {
      const connection = await amqp.connect(rabbitMQURL);
      const channel = await connection.createChannel();

      await channel.assertQueue(QueueEnum.MyQueue);
      channel.prefetch(1);
      await channel.consume(QueueEnum.MyQueue, async (message: any) => {
        try {
          if (message && message.content) {
            //Do processing logic here
            }
          } else {
            console.log("Null message here");
            // Here I think I should do something to delete that message and keep receiving
          }

          if (message !== null) {
            channel.ack(message);
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error processing message:', error);
          if (message !== null) {
            channel.ack(message);
          }
        }
      });

    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error consuming messages:', error);
    }
  }
```

}

The problem here is that if I receive a `null` message in the queue, the service stops processing future messages after the `null` one.

I've tried to do a `channel.ack(message)` or `channel.nack(message)` in the `ELSE` clause but that leads to a service break. I'm not sure what I'm missing here to keep processing messages after receiving a null message.

any ideas on this?

Comment: Did you solve this in the meantime?

Comment: yes, the error was that I implementented a function in the main to recreate the queue, that method was unnecesary and launched a null message that was consumed on the other side